# Check if checkbox is checked with dynamic ID

Tags: jquery, html

I read so many questions about this problem, but whatever I do, it doesn't work.

I have several checkboxes with dynamic IDs, like those:

```
More:
<input type="checkbox" name="more" id="checkbox-more-285">
<br> Extra:
<input type="checkbox" name="extra" id="checkbox-extra-285">

<button class="add_to_cart">
  Add to cart
</button>
```

The number 285 can be anything, that I use elsewhere.

Then I have this jQuery:

```
jQuery('.add_to_cart').click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();

  if (jQuery("[id^='checkbox-more-']:checked")) {
    console.log('1');
  }

  if (jQuery("[id^='checkbox-extra-']:checked")) {
    console.log('2');
  }
  return false;
});
```

As you can see on the jsFiddle here [https://jsfiddle.net/](https://jsfiddle.net/1Lj2y6gq/), whenever I click on add to cart button, both logs are on console.

Comment: try `jQuery("[id^='checkbox-more-']").is(":checked")`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not enough to test for the  jQuery collection, which will always be truthy. Add the `.length` property to the test, like this:

```
if (jQuery("[id^='checkbox-more-']:checked").length) { // etc...
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use either

```
jQuery("[id^='checkbox-more-']").is(":checked")
{
    console.log('1');
  }
```

or

```
if($("[id^='checkbox-more-']").prop('checked') == true){
    console.log('1');
}
```

Comment: `prop` may not be suitable here, since it only checks the first match, not the other elements that may also have such an `id`.